# What does the number mean in Bash's segfault message?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, segmentation-fault

I have a program that produces a segmentation fault, I'm running on Linux.

Running the program directly, I get:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

When I run it within a Bash script, I get:

```
./script.sh: line 1:  4095 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) ./prog
```

The number (4095 in my example) is different every time. It appears always to increase; if I run the script many times quickly, it seems to increase by 5 each time.

What does that number tell me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is the PID of the application that crashed. Every time you run an application it has a Process ID (PID). When your bash script ran bash determined that your application crashed and listed its PID alongside the reason it crashed.

You can always look in /proc/pid for information about any process in a UNIX system, and it can be quite helpful. See: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html

The PID of your application is listed next to it when you list processes using the `ps`command and can also be retrieved programatically if needed, see: http://linux.die.net/man/2/getpid

If you have an application that's hung you can hook a debugger to it, providing you know its PID and its name. For example, `gdb myprogram PID`